# Django: "Cannot resolve keyword 'email' into field. Choices are: created_at, expires_at, id, otp, user, user_id"

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to validate an OTP that was sent to the user when registering i have a separate model for otp which has an OneToOne relation with the user

**Otp Model**

```
class Verify(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(
    User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="userverify", blank=False, null=True)
otp = IntegerRangeField(
    min_value=111111, max_value=999999, blank=True, null=True)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(
    _("created at"), auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True, blank=False)
expires_at = models.TimeField(null=True)
```

the VerifySerializer: I don't specify the model because i only need it to check the validity of the input, although i think this might be the problem

```
class VerifySerializerBase(serializers.Serializer):
   email = serializers.EmailField()
   otp = serializers.CharField()
```

the Verify_Email view takes an email and otp value to validate the email

**How I'm trying to verify the otp**

```
class Verify_Email(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        try:
            data = request.data
            serializer = VerifySerializerBase(data=data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                email = serializer.data['email']
                otp = serializer.data['otp']
                verify = Verify.objects.filter(email=email, otp=otp)
                user = User.objects.filter(email=email)

                if not user[0].exists():
                    return Response({
                        'message': "A user with this email was not found"
                    }, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
                elif user[0].is_active:
                    return Response({
                        'message': "This email has already been verified"
                    }, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

                elif verify[0].exists():
                    if verify[0].expires_at >= datetime.now():
                        return Response({
                            'message': "This OTP has expired, please request another one"
                        }, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
                    elif verify[0].otp != otp:
                        return Response({
                            'message': "This OTP is invalid"
                        }, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
                    else:
                        verify[0].delete()
                        user[0].is_active = True
                        user[0].save()
                        return Response({
                            'message': "Email has been verified"
                        }, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
                return Response({
                    'message': "Something is wrong"
                }, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

            return Response({
                'message': "Something is wrong"
            }, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        except Exception as e:
            return Response(str(e), status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, template_name=None, content_type=None)
```

and when testing i get

```
"Cannot resolve keyword 'email' into field. Choices are: created_at, expires_at, id, otp, user, user_id"
```

from what I understand i think it's telling me that I'm checking for fields that are not in the OTP model fields but I don't think I'm doing that??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error relates to the models, not the serializer. This line implies that a `Verify` model has a field `email`, because you're building a query on that field:

```
verify = Verify.objects.filter(email=email, otp=otp)
```

Perhaps you meant to query by user instead, which involves swapping with the following line like so:

```
user = User.objects.get(email=email)
verify = Verify.objects.filter(user=user, otp=otp)
```

Comment: ``"The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing."``
yes that was indeed the mistake i just realized it, but the above error came up.

Comment: Ah yes, you should use `get` instead of `filter` for `user` -- answer updated.

Comment: another error came up saying "'User' object is not subscriptable" should i ask a new question and link it?

Comment: `User.objects.filter` was returning a list with one item, whereas `User.object.get` returns just that first element. So you can replace `user[0]` with `user`.

Comment: yeah but that means .exists() wouldn't work right?

Comment: The `get()` would throw a `User.DoesNotExist` exception, which you can wrap in a try/except to get the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

i think [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2070046/daniel-w-steinbrook) answer is correct but a little bit bugy
instead use

```py
 user = User.objects.get(email=email)
```

can use

```py
 user = User.objects.filter(email=email).first()
 if user is None:
   raise Exception("")
```

this is better because you can use your custom error handler
another problem is in your model if you have duplicate or more otp code
in this situation your queryset like

```py
verify = Verify.objects.filter(user=user, otp=otp)
```

returned a list of verify objects,obviously it's not good solution.
change model like below

```py
 class Verify(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        related_name="userverify", 
        blank=False, 
        null=True
    )
    otp = IntegerRangeField(
        min_value=111111, max_value=999999, blank=True, null=True
    )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(
        _("created at"), auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True, blank=False
    )
    expires_at = models.TimeField(null=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

now use

```py
 verify = Verify.objects.filter(user=user, otp=otp, is_active=True)
```

‍‍‍‍‍‍

Comment: I going to ask another question because i ran into another issue i think my whole code is buggy, and i changed the user relation in the verify model to just an email, i will send you a link to the new question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73686894/django-error-trying-to-validate-an-email-verification-otp here is the link to the question